# Salesforce Author Apex option not available under Administrative Permissions section

Tags: salesforce

I have created a new account in Sales force and trying to run the default API's from Developer Console.My account has System **Administrator** Role.

But, **Open Execute Anonymous Window** is disabled for me and am not able to run any API,getting error **'You don't have the permission to execute Apex'**.

So i tried to Enable **Author Apex** in SetUp,but i am not able to see that option under Administrative Permissions section
[image: Administrative Permissions section settings]

How to enable Author Apex? ,so that i can use the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

You should check user license assigned to your user. I think user license assigned to your user don't have author apex permission.

Comment: Actually i am exploring sales force,so created a trial account.Even i has System Administrator role,is there anything like trial account users can't access apex code,so that i did not got the "Author Apex" option to enable?.